# Vba code to ask confirmation on certain combobox selections

Tags: combobox

In Access 2010, I have a combobox on a form that displays 5 values and fills the number 1 to 5 respectively to the field in the table. If the user selects the 1st, 2nd or 5th, the value can be returned without confirmation. How can I add a code that asks "Do you really want to select [values 3 or 4]?" It would then either allow the user to proceed with that selected value, or otherwise the user would select the 1st, 2nd or 5th instead.